# size of a div equal to browser viewport and when i scoll down it scrolls for further content.

Tags: jquery, css, html

Hey guys i am trying to create a website in which the `headerContainer div` is equal to 100% **(which is crimson div here)** height and width of the viewport and the page is scrollable so that i can view other content.
the **height and width of the header div is set to `100%` and fits properly but i have to make it fixed or absolute position it to do that which makes the below content hide in back of the main div.**

here is the 
[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/FLhhp/)

Comment: Why is this question voted down.

Comment: Do I understand correctly... you want `#headerContainer` to be 100% of the height of the viewport. This would push the content in `#mainContainer` down (forcing the user to scroll?)

Comment: Something like this: http://jsfiddle.net/FLhhp/1/ ?

Comment: To avoid downvotes, include code in the question **and** a fiddle. No I didn't down vote.

Comment: @JackPattishallJr. that's exactly what i needed. hey make me an answer so i can select it as an correct answer. thanks..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I understand correctly, you would like `#headerContainer` to be `100%` of the height of the viewport. This would push the content in #mainContainer down (forcing the user to scroll?)

If so, you'll want to add a height to the parent container (in this case, the html,  body) so that `#headerContainer` has an element to base its own height off of.

```
html, body {
    height: 100%;
}
```

Here's an updated fiddle demonstrating the change:

http://jsfiddle.net/FLhhp/1/

Answer (score 1):

You have to tell the html and body how tall they are... otherwise, your 100% height doesn't know what it is 100% of.

```
html, body {
    height: 100%;
}
```